# Working with child EF entity properties based on an abstract class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First, with c#4.0 and Visual Studio 2012. The following are code snippets.

I have a base abstract class:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }        
}
```

from which I derive three entities:

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    public Nullable<int> NHSTrustID { get; set; }
    public virtual NHSTrust NHSTrust { get; set; }        
}

 public class User : Person
{
    public int NHSTrustID { get; set; }
    public virtual NHSTrust NHSTrust { get; set; }
}

public class Notifier : Person
{
    public int NotifierTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual NotifierType NotifierType { get; set; }        
}
```

The entities are declared as:

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Notifier> Notifiers { get; set; }
```

so that the Persons entity can be queries as well.

A `person` who could belong to any of the three derived entites. I need to know if a `person` has the property `NHSTrust`. (`Users` must have an `NHSTrust`, for `Contacts` it is optional and `Notifiers` don't have an NHS Trust.

I can see how to do it with lots of code, but is there an elegant way of doing this?

**UPDATE**
My current 'solution' is:

```
var tempPerson = dbContext.Persons.Find(personID);  
NHSTrust nHSTrust = null;

if (tempPerson is Contact)
{
    nHSTrust = dbContext.Contacts.Find(personID).NHSTrust;
}
else if (tempPerson is User)
{
    nHSTrust = dbContext.Users.Find(personID).NHSTrust;
}
if (nHSTrust != null) { // do something}
```

Is there a way of doing this with just a single trip to that database.

Comment: How would you do it? What have you currently tried? Have you looked into Reflection?

Comment: Your best bet would be to add another level of your inheritance hierarchy of which the types that have such a value inherit from that intermediate type.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Most reflection based solutions couldn't be translated into an EF query.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, okay. I was unaware of that. I learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried querying the Persons entity then using `typeof` to determine which it is then querying Users and Contact seperately to identify if they have the NHSTrust property. What I was wondering was if I can access child entity properties from the base class?

Comment: @PeterSmith Can you provide a psuedo-code example of your query?

Comment: @PeterSmith The properties aren't of the same type, so that would make it quite a lot harder.  If they were all of the same type then it would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another level of your inheritance hierarchy:

```
public abstract class TrustablePerson : Person
{
    public NHSTrust NHSTrust { get; set; }
}
public class Contact : TrustablePerson
{
    public Nullable<int> NHSTrustID { get; set; }
}
public class User : TrustablePerson
{
    public int NHSTrustID { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can add a `TrustablePerson` to your context that gets items of that type.

Comment: Thanks very much Servy - all is now clear once seen.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an abstraction-level issue, where an abstract class is probably unneeded. It doesn't really save you anything in such small classes. Additionally, because some of the derived types are so similar, if you really want to abstract this, you should probably use an interface.

However, to answer your question, you can use the `is` operator, or even use linq. It will be fairly long and a bit messy. Really, though, your problem is the abstraction.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The above are snippets to illustrate the problem and there was a good reasons for the design as above.